# any publications using power analysis on deep learning projects?

Tags: deep-learning, statistical-power

Previous to starting a deep learning project, is it meaningful to do statistical power analysis for the resulting evaluation metrics to test, given a model and sample size?

I have not seen this in any publication in the field, as most machine learning  classification publications just spit out a result (accuracy, or some summary of sensitivity, specificity or precision as AUC-ROC, or Dice score) and report a t-statistic on its significance vs another result. If this can be done, then surely a power analysis beforehand can be done too to estimate required sample sizes (which would only refer to test set sample size, as this is the only source of the resulting metrics mean and variance).

Nevertheless I am struggling to see the intuition behind this. Why is this missing in the machine learning literature, despite of there being a huge interest in sample size estimation?

Comment: What would you be inferring or testing?

Comment: I am trying to get a grasp at this independent from the specifics. But for the sake of an example, lets say in context of semantic segmentation, i.e. pixel-wise classification task. A power analysis would show how many cases we would need to classify for an effect of a given magnitude (one case being one classified pixel I guess), is this correct?